# set environment variable (REACT_APP_BASE_URL) value based on branch name / react with dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, docker, webpack, environment-variables

I am working on react project using Dockerfile.

I have different branches (dev, test, demo, stage..) I should run different base_url based on current branch name

what I did to solve this issue was:

-creating .env.dev .env.test ... files in project directory and store the environment variable like this in each created env file:

REACT_APP_BASE_URL'https://abc.branch-name.example'
it seems it works fine  locally !

my script:
[script file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXpH8.png)

related commands in my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11.2 as builder
WORKDIR /my-app

COPY . .

RUN npm rebuild node-sass
RUN npm run build
```

(I'm not allowed to use docker-compose.yaml)

when I push the code the builder run dockerfile and stay in (production mode), it ignores the environment variables  that was working locally .

The question is how can I let docker not ignoring my environment variables and detect the current branch?

- can webpack plugin solve this issue?

I don't prefer to change anything in docker cuz it was not created by me and I'm not familiar with docker, so please let me know if this issue can be fixed with webpack.

any suggestions would be helpful ,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating a .env.production file to specify environment variables for production as you did for the test and dev env, hope this works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).